# How to write csv file, column wise in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

```
with open('CSVFile.csv','a',newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(["First Name", "Last Name:", "Contacts_No", "Email","Skills"])
    print(len(First_Name))
    for i in range(0, len(First_Name)):
        writer.writerow(["%s" %(First_Name[i]), "%s" %(Last_Name[i]), "%s" %(Contacts[i]), "%s" %(Emails[i]), "%s" %(Skills)[i]])
```

I want to write the data into csv file like First_Name in one column, Last_Name in one column and so on. This code write well but all data in one column.

Comment: It's not your problem, but what are you hoping to achieve with e.g. `"%s" %(First_Name[i])`? Could you give example inputs and outputs? Why `newline=''`?

Comment: it write firstname, lastname, mobile, email, skills in one column, I want to write first name in one column, Lastname in second column and so on.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and give one, a description isn't that useful compared to actual text examples.